# How to Test @HystrixCommand fallback method in Springboot Application

Tags: spring-boot, hystrix, spring-boot-test

I am using @HystrixCommand as follows in a my method

```
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "fallbackCircuit", groupKey = "group-key", commandProperties = {
            @HystrixProperty(name = "requestCache.enabled", value = "true"),
            @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds", value = "5000")})

 public void someMethod(String input){
 ...
 }


 public void fallbackCircuit(String input, Throwable e){
 ...
 }
```

But I am not able to test the fallback method? The fallback method is not called in my tests. I think I have not setup the tests properly. What would be a better way of testing fallback method?

Answer (score 0):

Although not directly testing the fallback method, another question I've answered has a solution that shows the circuit breaker is triggered.
See [How can I unit-test javanica @HystrixCommand annotated methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43453513/how-can-i-unit-test-javanica-hystrixcommand-annotated-methods/47222256#47222256][1])
if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to test the @HystrixCommand() if you want to test the fallback method in your UT's you can directly call your fallback method in your unit tests and assert on its response/result.